# Email is not Receiving through Swift Mailer Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, email

- i tried to send  email through swiftmailer
- response code 200 ok but still no email recived.

controller code

```
 public function EmaiAction(Request $request)
 {
    $mailer = $this->get('mailer');

    $logger = new \Swift_Plugins_Loggers_ArrayLogger();
    $mailer->registerPlugin(new \Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));


    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Hello')
    ->setFrom('mohd@abc.com')
    ->setTo('***@gmail.com')
    ->setBody('This is a test email.');

    if ($this->get('mailer')->send($message)) {
    echo '[SWIFTMAILER] sent email to ';
    } else {
    echo '[SWIFTMAILER] not sending email: ' . $mailer->dump();
    }    

die("email send");

}
```

output

```
   [SWIFTMAILER] sent email to
```

config.yml

```
swiftmailer:
disable_delivery:  true
transport: smtp
encryption: ssl
port:   465
auth_mode: login
host:      smtp.gmail.com
username:  ***@gmail.com
password:  passwrd
delivery_address: abc@gmail.com
```

- on doing echo in if/else its going in if condition that means its true.
- so why im not recieving  emails.
- no error logs appears while sending an emails
- im using cpanel app is production enviornment.

Comment: have you given a valid to and from email address?

Comment: yes  i have given correct to and from

Comment: 'Allowing less secure apps to access your account'- did you made this on for gmail?

Comment: yes i did that and gmail ->setting allow imap enabled also

Comment: Try adding this your code- `$this->get('mailer')->send($message);` . Not in if condition.

Comment: do you check if the mail is redirecting to spam ?

Answer (score 1):

```
disable_delivery:  true
```

This disables mail sending for development (See [Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/dev_environment.html#disabling-sending))

Additionally try the swiftmailer config like this

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    username:  ***@gmail.com
    password:  passwrd
```

Comment: when i removed disable_delivery onnection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection refused #111]

Comment: Try changing the transport to gmail (http://symfony.com/doc/current/email/gmail.html)

Comment: still facing same problem

Comment: See updated answer. If you use 2FA for gmail, additional steps are needed. See the docs for that.

Comment: i also tried this config but still it did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
->setSubject('Hello')
->setFrom('mohd@abc.com')
->setTo('***@gmail.com')
->setBody('This is a test email.');
$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Comment: try same thing now im getting  connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com